# TYPO3: How to create a Dropdown in own Extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm creating a filter in my extension, and i need there a dropdown from the entries of a table in the extension (in my example the colors table). I tried this:

```
<select class="option-set clearfix form-control" data-filter-group="farben">
        <option value="*" data-filter-value="" class="selected">Alle Farben</option>
        <f:for each="{steines}" as="steine">
            <option value="#filter-farben-{steine.farbe.name}" data-filter-value=".{steine.farbe.name}">{steine.farbe.name}</option>
        </f:for>
    </select>
```

The Problem hereby is that the entries will be displayed multiple. For example:

- Red
- Green
- Blue
- Red
- Blue
- Blue
  etc.

But it should be:

- Red
- Green
- Blue

Any ideas?

Thx for your help!

Comment: why do you have multiple Blue in the collection ?

Comment: I think that is because the script gives for every item - i have in the pool i want to filter - the color of this item to the dropdown. I've build the extension with the Extension builder. there i have a seperate table for the colors. There is of course every color just once listet. and now i want to have these "color-list" from the table as a dropdown. 
I know a picture would be useful, but i've not to much credits.

hope you can help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you can see my and `derhansen` small discussion the problem is in your collection.

If you will pass in collection: Red, Blue, Blue, Blue, Yellow, Yellow then your loop will display every position from collection. The same thing will be with select viewhelper

The thing you should is to create a seperate collection that groups colors and will have only one instance of each color. Than you can go with your loop or with the viewhelper

For example you can create a simple query to database (if you have this info stored in db) using simple `GROUP BY`. Other solution is to iterate in in controller

```
$tmpCollection = array();
foreach($collection as $color) {
    if(!in_array($color, $tmpCollection) {
        $tmpCollection[] = $color;
    }
}
```

than you can pass `$tmpCollection` to view and it will only contain one instance of color. Ofc course this is just pseudo code but you get the feeling of the solution :)

Comment: perhaps my comment in the topic helps to help. :)

Comment: @codeFragment this is the case I've described to you. You need to have seperate collection with grouped colors. The case you've described indicates that db query will be the best solution for that

Comment: sorry i was a little bit confused :) yes, i'll try this. thank you a lot.

Comment: How do i have to create a simple query to database? i have only a "SteineRepository.php" not a "ColorRepository.php".

Comment: @codeFragment you can create a method in SteinRepository that will do something like `SELECT color FROM table GROUP BY color`

Answer (score 1):

Why do you create the select and all options manually? TYPO3 Fluid has a [select ViewHelper](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Form/Select.html) which renders a select-field with all given options?

You should pass all available colors to your view (e.g. `$this->view->assign('colors', $this->colorRepository->findAll());`. Then use the colors in the select ViewHelper.

```
<f:form.select property="yourProperty" options="{colors}" prependOptionValue="*" prependOptionLabel="Alle Farben" />
```

Comment: IMO it will give the same result cause select VH makes almoust the same thing like codeFragment did. So if he pass there collection with multiple Blue options it will render the same thing

Comment: Ah, now I've got the initial problem. I think codeFragment wants to create a filter for all colors, which are associated to a collection of "seines" objecs. codeFragment should pass the collection of available colors to the view.

Comment: perhaps my comment in the topic helps to help. :)